# C++/CLI how to store a native reference inside a managed class right

Tags: c++, c++-cli, wrapper

i need ffmpeg wrapper for using on c#.
one class is wrap of AVPacket:

```
`extern "C"
{
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>       // here is AVPacket
}

using namespace System;


public ref class VideoPacket
{
public: 
    property DateTime Time
    {
        DateTime get() { return _time; }
    }

    property bool IsIFrame
    {
        bool get() { return _packet->flags == 1; }
    }

    ~VideoPacket()
    {
        av_packet_unref(_packet);
    }
internal:
    VideoPacket(AVPacket packet, DateTime time)
    {
        _packet = &packet;
        _time = time;
    }

private:        
    DateTime _time; 
    AVPacket* _packet;
};`
```

also i have cpp class Reader:

```
VideoPacket^ Reader::Read()
{
    AVPacket packet = _reader->ReadVideoPacket();
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime::Now;
    int s = packet.size;
    bool iFrame = packet.flags == 1;
    VideoPacket^ p = gcnew VideoPacket(packet, dateTime);
    return p;
}
```

it's work fine if i call it in c++ app.

[debbug pointer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4qlB.png)

but when i call it from c# app the AVPacket* set all fields to default (see picture below). c# code:

```
VideoPacket packet = _reader.Read();
byte[] data = packet.get();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g42pM.png)

what i must do to store AVPacket pointer right

Comment: The code is storing a pointer to a temporary C++ object.  So that's a dangling pointer after Read() completes.  The C++/CLI compiler will not permit you to declare the member as AVPacket instead of AVPacket*, far too risky with a garbage collector.  You have to make a copy yourself, use `new` for storage and `delete` in the destructor and finalizer.  Or, usually better, just copy the members of the AVPacket you need.

Comment: @Hans Passant can i mark you comment as answer? you are right: it need use _packet = new AVPacket(packet);

Comment: You can't.  Just show us how you solved it in your own post and mark it as the answer.